# How to grab Azure variables when running Karate tests?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to run my Karate tests in Azure as a pipeline. In order to execute the tests, I need to first grab some environment variables defined in the pipeline itself. I configure these variables in config.js hoping to make them available to use in the tests. Currently, I have something like this:

```
# azure-pipelines.yml

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- name: user_secret
  value: "foo"

steps:

 - task: Maven@3
   inputs:
     mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
     goals: test
     publishJUnitResults: true
     testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
     javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
     mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
     mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
     effectivePomSkip: false
     sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

```
// config.js

function fn(){
    return  {
        secret: user_secret
    };
}
```

The error I get though is `"user_secret" is not defined`

I am being told I can debug it locally because the pipeline is providing the values as environment variables, and that I should be able to validate that locally by setting the variables when I run my code. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Similar to the above example, I also tried to get the variable `process.env.user_secret`, but this didn't work for me either.

How can I access Azure variables with my code?